# Installing PhP curl on Ubuntu Amazon EC2

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, amazon-ec2

Im new to Amazon Ec2 and I'm 'NOT AN EXPERT', after I installed my word-press blog I found that Facebook comments of users are disabled, May be because I need to enable PhP Curl on the server (Im guessing). I need a help on how to do that please, and I would really appreciate if you explain it in details so I can help my self as a beginner.
I really appreciate your help :)
Im Mac user
AMI: bitnami-wordpress-3.3-2-linux-x64-ubuntu-10.04-ebs (ami-6938ed00)

Comment: i had no experience in using Amazon EC2, but in Debian based Linux distro, if you have root access via SSH, you can just do `apt-get install php5-curl`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install PHP-curl using the command


`sudo apt-get install php5-curl`


Also you may have to enable it in php.ini if it is commented using ;(semicolon) in it.

Comment: Normally, it's enabled upon installation.

Comment: Well you are right, but that will depend on bitnami-wordpress ami whether they have played with curl or not.

Comment: I usually start with a fress ami for amazon ec2 server and hence it starts automatically. But in case you are using other's ami, it may have issues with it.

Comment: Yea, could be anything... Any distro has its own setup

Comment: Would you please explain where to write this code, Im sorry but Im really a beginner in EC2 ! MAC user

Comment: Do you have access to SSH access to your server? If you don't have it, you cant run this command. Google for SSH client for MAC and download it, configure it for your ec2 instance and connect to terminal. then paste this command there and execute. It will do the rest

Answer (score 1):

BitNami WordPress uses it owns PHP version which already includes curl (not the ubuntu PHP). If you run `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php -m` you will see curl in the list of modules loaded.

`sudo apt-get install php5-curl` would install curl in the system php which is not the php that is using your WordPress installation (from BitNami).