# PHP 5.6 will not run CURL

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.6.11 and running Apache/2.4.12.  I've installed CURL by running

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

and restarting: `sudo service apache2 restart`

At the command line I type `curl -V` and get the following:

```
curl 7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

and when I type `which curl` I get the following: `/usr/bin/curl`

So I'm fairly certain that curl is installed.

When I use `phpinfo()` on a php page called from a web browser, there is no block for curl and any reference to curl for that matter.

My understanding was that curl should work fine based on this [question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5) without any configuration changes which is clearly not the case.

Can someone point me in the right direction to modify PHP config files or what commands I need to run to get CURL to run with PHP on my version?

Attached are the config file locations found in phpinfo()

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2

Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d

Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

Comment: You may need to `a2enmod curl` or something along those lines. Check the `.ini` files/directory shown in `phpinfo()` output and see if it's being properly loaded there.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?  I updated the config files referenced in phpinfo().  Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled the `curl` extension? Check for `extension=curl.so` in your PHP configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PhP curl on Ubuntu Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715693/installing-php-curl-on-ubuntu-amazon-ec2)

Comment: Make sure that you alter the right php.ini, CLI and apache have their own copies.  Look in the browser version of phpinfo() to see the right file to alter.

Comment: @bishop how is it a duplicate when the accepted answer for that question does not work when tried?  sudo apt-get install php5-curl  ... does NOT work.

Comment: Because the accepted answer _also_ says "you may have to enable it in php.ini if it is commented using ;(semicolon) in it", which you've not addressed in your post and is, likely, the cause.

Comment: @bishop enabled it how?  What do you check for in php.ini?  The answer in that regard is vague and incomplete.

Comment: What's the output of `grep -Ri curl /etc/php*`?

Comment: Output @bishop is this: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/99-curl.ini:extension=curl.so
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:[curl]
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This  is required to be an
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:;curl.cainfo =
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:[curl]
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is r                                                                                           equired to be an
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:;curl.cainfo =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that the extension is *installed* (with relevant example output):

```
$ sudo find / -name curl.so\*
/usr/lib64/php/7.0/modules/curl.so
```

Then, check that the extension is *enabled* (again with relevant output):

```
$ grep -Ri curl /etc/php*
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini:extension=curl.so
```

---

If the first command doesn't produce any output, then the module wasn't installed. You'll need to diagnose why your system package manager didn't install the package. For Ubuntu, you might need to run `sudo apt-get update`.

If the first command worked, but the second didn't, you'll need to enable the extension, then restart Apache afterwards:

```
echo 'extension=curl.so' | sudo tee /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/99-curl.ini
```

Comment: I have a 20-json.ini but no 99*

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed. This command aims to _create_ a new file, to enable the extension.

Comment: No problem, so restart apache after?  Is this a permanent fix?

Comment: Yes, restart and yes, permanent. You likely will need a similar line for the CLI configuration, which I'd guess is in `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d`. (I don't use Ubuntu, so I'm guessing here. Exercise judgement.)

Comment: Hmmm...it appears to have added but I still see no curl block in phpinfo()

Comment: Is the `99-curl.ini` file listed as one of the parsed INI files in the output of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160014/discussion-between-rocco-the-taco-and-bishop).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.
`sudo php5enmod curl`

Or,

Check your php.ini file.
Find in page for `extension=php_curl`
If there is `;` symbol, remove this symbol on the begining of the line.

Comment: Hmm. Is there `;` symbol in of curl line in php.ini file ?

Comment: No, I did a search on php.ini and only have this: [curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
;curl.cainfo =

Answer (score 0):

provided that you initially installed apache & mod-php via apt-get, correct, that should be sufficient, in which case, my best guess is that curl is indeed installed, but get an error during initialization, and that `display_startup_errors` is off. enable `display_startup_errors`, restart apache, load a php page, and check your error logs, there's probably a line there saying why the curl module couldn't be loaded.